# Creating different arrays: not displaying correct results

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, sorting

I am currently building a sorting program. I have made three different ways to create an array: `Random`, `In Order` and `Reverse`.  I am currently undergoing problems with the `In Order` and `Reverse` arrays. Every time an `In Order` array is created it starts with a `1`, I am not sure how come is doing so. Also my `Reverse` array will display digits out of order not every time but after some clicks.  How can I fix these two issues?

```
namespace sortingMachine
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Class Level Variables --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        Random r = new Random();
        OpenFileDialog open1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        long operations = 0;
        int size;
        int max;
        int[] createArray;
        int[] sortArray;
        int[] copyArray;

        //Create Array Methods --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        public void RandomNumber()
        {
            size = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxSize.Text);
            max = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxMax.Text);
            createArray = new int[size];
            copyArray = new int[size];
            sortArray = new int[size];

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                createArray[i] = r.Next(1, max);
            }

            textBoxResults.AppendText("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine + "Random" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);

            DisplayArrays();
        }

        public void InOrder()
        {
            size = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxSize.Text);
            max = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxMax.Text);
            createArray = new int[size];
            copyArray = new int[size];
            sortArray = new int[size];

            createArray[0] = 1;

            for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
            {
                createArray[i] = createArray[i - 1] + r.Next(1, max);
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
            {
                if (r.Next(1, 101) < Convert.ToInt32(textBoxPercentage.Text))
                {
                    for (int x = 1; x < size; x++)
                    {
                        createArray[x] = r.Next(1, createArray[size - 1]);
                    }
                }
            }

            textBoxResults.AppendText("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine + "In Order" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);

            DisplayArrays();
        }

        public void ReverseOrder()
        {
            size = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxSize.Text);
            max = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxMax.Text);
            createArray = new int[size];
            copyArray = new int[size];
            sortArray = new int[size];

            createArray[size - 1] = 1;

            for (int i = size - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                createArray[i - 1] = createArray[i] + r.Next(1, max);
            }

            for (int i = size - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                if (r.Next(1, 101) < createArray[0])
                {
                    for (int x = size - 1; x > 0; x--)
                    {
                        createArray[x] = r.Next(1, createArray[0]);
                    }
                }
            }

            textBoxResults.AppendText("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine + "Reverse Order" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);

            DisplayArrays();
        }



        private void buttonCreateArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if ((textBoxSortKey.Text != "") && (textBoxCreateKey.Text != ""))
            {
                if (radioButtonRandom.Checked == true)
                {
                    RandomNumber();
                }

                if (radioButtonInOrder.Checked == true)
                {
                    InOrder();
                }

                if (radioButtonReverseOrder.Checked == true)
                {
                    ReverseOrder();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Type a key into the Key textbox.");
            }
        }



    }
}
```

**Display Results:**

*The order array I am not sure why it always start with one:*

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
In Order
1
2
4
6
10
```

*There are times the reverse order array will be like this:*

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Reverse Order
    10
    2
    7
    6
    5
```

Windows Form:

[image]

Comment: did you debug it? Go through your code step by step and look at the values that are being changed.

Comment: It would really help if you'd show a short but complete program which demonstrates your problem and *nothing* else. A console app would make this a lot easier to reproduce.

Comment: @JonSkeet It is a complete example program. All that is needed is to copy paste and name the text boxes correspondingly in the windows form. Please help me.

Comment: @charliecodex23: No, I've got to start up Visual Studio, create a new Windows Forms project, start dragging controls all over the place. You're the one requiring help, so it's up to you to put in the effort to make it as easy as possible *to* help you. With a console app, I can copy, paste into a text editor, compile and run - I'm done in 30 seconds. Likewise, your program does more than it needs to in order to demonstrate the problem. Again, it's up to you to spend the time to shrink it to *just* what's required.

Comment: I agree with JonSkeets advice, especially on what shows all the signs of being your homework.  In fact, if you can include just one function or a series of statements, for those of us who use Linqpad (highly recommended) to paste into, you will make it even more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at how you are assigning values to the array you'll see that the first element is assigned zero, but in your loop you start at the second element (i.e. `1`) so you never re-assign the first element.

```
        createArray[0] = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        {
            createArray[i] = createArray[i - 1] + r.Next(1, max);
        }
```

Try writing the first element assignment like this:

```
        createArray[0] = r.Next(1, max);
```

As for your reverse function, there's too much weirdness in there to really see what you're trying to do. Try thinking thru it a few more times. Especially be careful with code like this: `if (r.Next(1, 101) < createArray[0])` - it has random behaviour and also magic numbers in it.

Answer (score 0):

In the function InOrder you initialize your first index of your array to 1.  As for the Reverse Order, in the *if* statement in between the two fors, each time you are comparing a random number between 1-101 with the first number in your array.  What you should be doing instead is compare the numbers in your array with each other.

Comment: +1 could you show me how you will make the change for the `reverse order` with using my example code?